# Port 22 operation timed out

Tags: git

Want to create a project in GIT where I can send my project to others. I created a project on git and now trying to setup the remote. Here is what I did. I set up an SSH key too. What is my issue?[image]

Comment: looks like your remote is either not configured correctly or you haven't setup the remote. Maybe you need to provide your ssh key

Comment: i did that... so is it anything I should add in the config file?

Comment: Try to log in via ssh. Still getting a time out?

Comment: "timed out" usually means you're on an evil network that blocks non-HTTP(S) traffic. Sometimes it only blocks it until you fill in a stupid nonstandard password form (whereas WPA is standard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, confirm that you can ssh into the remote site. If you can, double check that the remote repository exists. When adding a remote to an existing local project, my workflow looks like this:

```
$ ssh example.com mkdir ~/repo/myproject
$ ssh example.com git init --bare ~/repo/myproject
$ cd myproject
$ git remote add origin ssh://example.com/~/repo/myproject
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```